# How to Annotate Seaborn Bar Plot with separate values (dates) from col of Dataframe which is not plotted

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a Pandas DataFrame where I have plot a Seaborn Bar Plot, as shown (edit: image not appearing).

I wish to annotate on each bar, the date_install value. I have searched high and low, and can only see references to annotating the bars with the y value of the bar itself.

The price is plotted on the y-axis, with the part_no plotted on the x-axis.

Is this possible within Seaborn?

Thanks

[image: Bar Plot requiring annotation]

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data1 = {
    'date_install': ['2020-02-02','2020-04-03', '2019-03-02'],
    'part_no':['D235','S222','S211'],
    'price': ['1500', '2000', '1600']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
sns.barplot(x=df.part_no, y=df.price)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data1 = {
    'date_install': ['2020-02-02','2020-04-03', '2019-03-02'],
    'part_no':['D235','S222','S211'],
    'price': ['1500', '2000', '1600']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)

plt.figure()
ax = sns.barplot(x=df.part_no, y=df.price)

for p,date in zip(ax.patches, data1['date_install']):
    ax.annotate(date, xy=(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2, p.get_height()),
                ha='center', va='bottom')
```

[image]

Comment: This results in `TypeError: Neither the x nor y variable appears to be numeric.` because `'prince'` values are string type. `plt.figure()` is not needed, and it's easier to use `_ = ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=df.date_install)` instead of the `for-loop`.